# Android firebase pushnotification minimum version issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebaseui

I created a firebase push notification app, with min version 16 in gradle file. When i change it to 15 or lesser than that i am getting an error showing

> uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library D:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.firebaseui\firebase-ui-auth\0.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui.auth" to force usage

The dependencies i used in project gradle is

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'}
```

and in app gradle is

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'
```

How can i use push notification in api levels lesser than 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not from the push notification, its from this library that you are using:

> com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth
>
> FirebaseUI is an open-source library that offers simple, customizable UI bindings on top of the core Firebase SDKs. It aims to eliminate boilerplate code and promote best practices (both user experience and security) for authentication.

Here is a link to learn more about it:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth

To solve your problem, go to the manifest file and add this:

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui.auth" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed " compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0' " from my dependency and added it to manifest. Now its working fine. Thank you so much.